# Switching data source of layer to new feature class using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro 2.0?

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro, data-source

A common ArcPy coding pattern that I used with ArcGIS Pro 1.4 (and earlier) no longer works at ArcGIS Pro 2.0.

I have an ArcGIS Pro project with one map called Map, and that map has one layer called Test Layer.  Test Layer has as its data source a file geodatabase feature class called testFC.

I have used the Select tool to create a new feature class called testFC2 which is a subset of testFC (so it has an identical schema).

In ArcPy at ArcGIS Pro 1.4 I had no trouble switching the data source of Test Layer from testFC to testFC2 in the same file geodatabase using this code:

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\temp\test.aprx")
mapx = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
lyr = mapx.listLayers("Test Layer")[0]
lyr.dataSource = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFC2"
```

However, the same code at ArcGIS Pro 2.0 gives:

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

I checked the [help for the Layer class](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm) and that now says that the `dataSource` property is now Read Only whereas previously it was Read and Write.

The same help page says:

> Changing a layer's data source is a common requirement. There is a
>   method and a property on the Layer object that help with this. For a
>   more detailed discussion, parameter information, scenarios, and code
>   samples, please refer to the [Updating and fixing data sources](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm)
>   help topic.

I can find no suitable code sample to use in place of my coding pattern at [Updating and fixing data sources](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm) which seems to be focussed on switching workspaces of data sources.

**How do we switch the data source of a layer to a new feature class using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro 2.0?**

The same issue seems to have been noted at [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/197567-arcpy-connectionproperties-become-read-only-in-pro-20#comment-697913) where Marco Boeringa says:

> The "dataSource" property of the Layer class also seems to have become
>   Read Only. However, you can use the "updateConnectionProperties" on
>   the same class to solve this

However, I think his situation must have been slightly different because I cannot see how `updateConnectionProperties` can be used to answer my question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me this seems far less intuitive, but it looks like it can still be done, using a partial replace of the connection properties dictionary:

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\temp\test.aprx")
mapx = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
lyr = mapx.listLayers("Test Layer")[0]
# Line below works at 1.4
# lyr.dataSource = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFC2"  
# Lines below can do the same thing at 2.0
connPropDict = lyr.connectionProperties
origDataset = connPropDict['dataset']
lyr.updateConnectionProperties({'dataset':origDataset}, {'dataset':"testFC2"})
```

---

In the test above both new and old feature classes were in the same file geodatabase.  However, if "testFC2" had been in a different file geodatabase (perhaps `C:\Temp\test2.gdb`) then I replaced the last three lines of code above with:

```
origConnPropDict = lyr.connectionProperties
newConnPropDict = {'connection_info': {'database': r"C:\Temp\test2.gdb"},
                   'dataset': "testFC2",
                   'workspace_factory': 'File Geodatabase'}
lyr.updateConnectionProperties(origConnPropDict, newConnPropDict)
```